# Regex to extract phone number

Tags: c#, .net, regex

```
<CallInfo info: from '600000000', to '800000000', forwardedFrom '', display '', category '1', tollCategory '2',callingNumberRestricted false, custom '', receivingComplete true> -- (SUCCESS)
```

I have a huge text file with many lines like that. Can some one please help me with how to build Regex so that I can extract number `'800000000'`?

The from and to phone numbers will be **different**.

I always need the number which is follwed by `to`

Currently I am splitting the line at empty spaces and then iterating through the array which I feel is very inefficient.

Comment: If you know exactly what character the phone number begins and ends at for each line then that will probably be more efficient than Regex.

Comment: @vcsjones: Agreed; if all the lines look like this one you could treat it as fixed-length at least up through the phone numbers.

Comment: nope. There are many other lines other than this one. I am only interested in the line with this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `to '(\d{9})`.  That will match any sequence of 9 digits in a row after the text `to '`, and store the result in the first capture group.

Comment: That will match both the from and to numbers. The question specifically says that only the to number should be matched.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to get the whole match of the to-Number:

```
, to '[0-9]{9}',
```

After that you have to get a group from the match. You better take a named group like this:

```
, to '(?<toNumber>[0-9]{9})',
```

An implementation for getting the phone-number-to could look like this:

```
string regex = ", to '(?<toNumber>[0-9]{9})',";
string text = "<CallInfo info: from '600000000', to '800000000', forwardedFrom '', display '', category '1', tollCategory '2',callingNumberRestricted false, custom '', receivingComplete true> -- (SUCCESS)";
string toNumber = string.Empty;

Match match = Regex.Match(text, regex);
if (match.Success)
{
    toNumber = match.Groups["toNumber"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. I'm not sure how variant your input is though...

```
        string s = "<CallInfo info: from '600000000', to '800000000', forwardedFrom '', display '', category '1', tollCategory '2',callingNumberRestricted false, custom '', receivingComplete true> -- (SUCCESS)";

        Regex r = new Regex("^<CallInfo.* to '(\\d{9})'");
        var match = r.Match(s);
        var number = match.Groups[1];
```

Comment: (Having said that, I'm not sure it's more efficient than splitting lines. Regex isn't exactly a model of efficiency)

Comment: You don't really need the first and third capturing groups, you can simply use: `"^<CallInfo.* to '(\\d{9})'"`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks simple enough. I would take a "sample" line from your file and turn it into the Regex, marking and replacing real data with the special characters that indicate the types of data you're interested in. Specifically, you say you want to capture the "to" phone number:

```
@"^<CallInfo info: from '\d{1,9}', to '(?<toNumber>\d{1,9})', forwardedFrom '.*?', display '.*?', category '.*?', tollCategory '.*?', callingNumberRestricted (?:true|false), custom '.*?', receivingComplete (?:true|false)> -- \(SUCCESS\)$"
```

Running the entire file against this pattern using Regex.Match(), you can produce a list of the "to" numbers with the following code:

```
List<string> toNumbers = Regex.Match(contentsOfFile, pattern).Groups["toNumber"].ToList();
```

You can convert the numbers to actual numeric values with a simple parse:

```
List<ulong> toNumbersAsLongs = toNumbers.Select(s=>ulong.Parse(s)).ToList();
```

If you ever need any other data from this file, simply wrap that field in the pattern with parenthesis and give it a name using the `?<captureName>` convention.